# Setting custom control properties from Style XAML

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, dependency-properties, windows-store

I made custom control for metro application and want to set its properties from Style. But it's setters are not called.

Control property:

```
    public int FramesCount
    {
        get { return _framesCount; }
        set
        {
            _framesCount = value;
            if (ImageFileMask != null) ReloadFrames();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FramesCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FramesCount", typeof(int),
            typeof(MyControl), null
        );
```

XAML style:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MyControl" x:Key="wmLoadingBoxWaiting">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="FramesCount" Value="1"/>
</Style>
```

And page XAML:

```
<controls:MyControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="645,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource wmLoadingBoxWaiting}"/>
```

Standard properties (Width and Height) are setted properly, byt costom property FramesCount does not. Its setter calls only when I set it directly in page XAML instead setting style.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution:

```
    public int FramesCount
    {
        get { return _framesCount; }
        set
        {
            _framesCount = value;
            if (ImageFileMask != null) ReloadFrames();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FramesCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FramesCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(MyControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
            {
                (d as MyControl).FramesCount = (int)e.NewValue;
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `FramesCount` definition:

```
public int FramesCount
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FramesCountProperty ); }
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(FramesCountProperty , value); 
        if (ImageFileMask != null) ReloadFrames();
    }
}
```